# Forecasting with VAR model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, stationarity, vector-autoregression

Suppose we want to build a VAR model with two non stationary historical series $\{X_t\}$ and $\{Y_t\}$ .

Let us further suppose that in orded to get stationarity I should tranform the series differently from one another, i.e.
$$Z_t=X_t - X_{t-1} \text{ for }X_t $$
$$H_t = Y_t - Y_{t-2} \text{ for }Y_t$$

1. Should I have a "common" differential order for properly fit my model?
2. Forecasting differentiated series does not provide correct unit measure; consequently I have to perform some sort of "rollback" procedure; in this case ( for $\hat{X}_{t+1} = Z_t + X_{t-1}) $ and in order to get $\hat{X}_{t+3}$ I must know $X_{t+1}$.
   Should I use $\hat{X}_{t+1}  $ for the purpose? How does this effects my forecasting on subsequent values?